# If $V$ is a vector space, $W$ and $U$ are subspaces of $V$, why is $U^0, W^0 \supseteq ( U \cap W)^0$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

If $\textsf V$ is a vector space, $\textsf W$ and $\textsf U$ are subspaces of $\textsf V$, why is $\textsf U^0, \textsf W^0 \supseteq (\textsf U \cap \textsf W)^0$ true?

My mind tells me that the containment should happen in the other direction : if $A$ is a subspace of $B$, isn't $B^{0}\subseteq A^{0}$?

For clarification
$$A^{0} := \{ \phi \in \textsf{V}^* : \, \phi(a) = 0 \textrm{ for all } a \in A \}$$

Comment: You are right, it should be the other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. If, say, $V=\mathbb R^2$, $U=\mathbb R(1,0)$, and $W=\mathbb R(0,1)$, then $(U\cap W)^\circ=\{0\}^\circ=(\mathbb R^2)^*$. And, clearly, $U^\circ,W^\circ\varsubsetneq(\mathbb R^2)^*$.